# Настройка Outlook 2013 посредством vbs

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Собственно, есть рабочий скрипт:

```
On Error Resume Next 
const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject( "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
RegistryFolder = "Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\"

LDAPdisplayname = "Адресная книга"
LDAPserver = "dc4"
LDAPport = "389"
LDAPsearchbase = "ou=Автодор,dc=avtodor,dc=local"


'Add Ldap Type Key
sKeyPath = RegistryFolder & "e8cb48869c395445ade13e3c1c80d154\"
oReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath 
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "00033009", Array(0,0,0,0)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "00033e03", Array(&H23,0,0,0)
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3001", "Microsoft LDAP Directory"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3006", "Microsoft LDAP Directory"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e300a", "EMABLT.DLL"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d09", "EMABLT"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d13", "{6485D268-C2AC-11D1-AD3E-10A0C911C9C0}"
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01023d0c", Array(&H5c,&Hb9,&H3b,&H24,&Hff,&H71,&H07,&H41,&Hb7,&Hd8,&H3b,&H9c,&Hb6,&H31,&H79,&H92)

'Add Ldap connection settings key
sKeyPath = RegistryFolder & "5cb93b24ff710741b7d83b9cb6317992\"
oReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "00033009", Array(&H20,0,0,0)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "000b6613", Array(0,0)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "000b6615", Array(&H01,&H00)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "000b6622", Array(&H01,&H00)
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3001", LDAPdisplayname
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d09", "EMABLT"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d0a", "BJABLR.DLL"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d0b", "ServiceEntry"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e3d13", "{6485D268-C2AC-11D1-AD3E-10A0C911C9C0}"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6600", LDAPserver
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6601", LDAPport
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6602", ""
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6603", LDAPsearchbase
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6604", "(&(mail=*)(|(mail=%s*)(|(cn=%s*)(|(sn=%s*)(givenName=%s*)))))"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6605", "SMTP"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6606", "mail"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6607", "60"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6608", "100"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6609", "120"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660a", "15"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660b", ""
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660c", "OFF"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660d", "OFF"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660e", "NONE"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e660f", "OFF"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6610", "postalAddress"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6611", "cn"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath , "001e6612", "1"
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "001e67f1", Array(&H0a)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01023615", Array(&H50,&Ha7,&H0a,&H61,&H55,&Hde,&Hd3,&H11,&H9d,&H60,&H00,&Hc0,&H4f,&H4c,&H8e,&Hfa)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01023d01", Array(&He8,&Hcb,&H48,&H86,&H9c,&H39,&H54,&H45,&Had,&He1,&H3e,&H3c,&H1c,&H80,&Hd1,&H54)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01026631", Array(&H98,&H17,&H82,&H92,&H5b,&H43,&H03,&H4b,&H99,&H5d,&H5c,&Hc6,&H74,&H88,&H7b,&H34)
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "101e3d0f", Array(&H02,&H00,&H00,&H00,&H0c,&H00,&H00,&H00,&H17,&H00,&H00,&H00,&H45,&H4d,&H41,&H42,&H4c,&H54,&H2e,&H44,&H4c,&H4c,&H00,&H42,&H4a,&H41,&H42,&H4c,&H52,&H2e,&H44,&Hc,&H4c,&H00)

'Append to Backup Key for ldap types
sKeyPath = RegistryFolder & "9207f3e0a3b11019908b08002b2a56c2\"
oReg.getBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,sKeyPath, "01023d01",Backup
Dim oldLength
oldLength = UBound (Backup)
ReDim Preserve Backup(oldLength+16)
Backup(oldLength+1) = &He8
Backup(oldLength+2) = &Hcb
Backup(oldLength+3) = &H48
Backup(oldLength+4) = &H86
Backup(oldLength+5) = &H9c
Backup(oldLength+6) = &H39
Backup(oldLength+7) = &H54
Backup(oldLength+8) = &H45
Backup(oldLength+9) = &Had
Backup(oldLength+10) = &He1
Backup(oldLength+11) = &H3e
Backup(oldLength+12) = &H3c
Backup(oldLength+13) = &H1c
Backup(oldLength+14) = &H80
Backup(oldLength+15) = &Hd1
Backup(oldLength+16) = &H54
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01023d01", Backup


'Append to Backup Key for ldap connection settings
sKeyPath = RegistryFolder & "9207f3e0a3b11019908b08002b2a56c2\"
oReg.getBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,sKeyPath, "01023d0e",Backup
oldLength = UBound (Backup)
ReDim Preserve Backup(oldLength+16)
Backup(oldLength+1) = &H5c
Backup(oldLength+2) = &Hb9
Backup(oldLength+3) = &H3b
Backup(oldLength+4) = &H24
Backup(oldLength+5) = &Hff
Backup(oldLength+6) = &H71
Backup(oldLength+7) = &H07
Backup(oldLength+8) = &H41
Backup(oldLength+9) = &Hb7
Backup(oldLength+10) = &Hd8
Backup(oldLength+11) = &H3b
Backup(oldLength+12) = &H9c
Backup(oldLength+13) = &Hb6
Backup(oldLength+14) = &H31
Backup(oldLength+15) = &H79
Backup(oldLength+16) = &H92
oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "01023d0e", Backup


'Delete Active Books List Key
sKeyPath = RegistryFolder & "9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\{ED475419-B0D6-11D2-8C3B-00104B2A6676}"
oReg.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath
```

Собственно адресная книга добавляется, метка поиска контактов в ad четко прописывается куда нужно, затык в том, что галочка настройки базы поиска ( что в настройке почты в меню "Каталог Microsoft LDap"-Поиск) стоит в графе "по умолчанию" и нужно ее выставить на пункт "другая", где и прописывается фильтр. Из-за этого в адресную книгу сыпятся все пользователи из AD, а не из определенной прописанной ou. Где эта дрянь пишется в реестре я так и не нашел.

Следующая проблема: таки не удаляется активная адресная книга, как была, так и есть на месте. Буду рад любой помощи, голову уже сломал.

Comment: Методом научного тыка нашел параметр, отвечающий за положение галочки: 00036623 REG_BINARY имеет значение 01,00,00,00 . Мне же необходимо перевести его в состояние 00,00,00,00. Вопрос как это сделать в рамках данного скрипта? пробовал по аналогии вписать oReg.SetBinaryValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath,  "00036623", Array(00,00,00,00), не прокатывает, значение уходит в 00 00. В vbs разбираюсь плохо, тонкостей команд не знаю((

Comment: разобрался самостоятельно (прописывал неправильный путь) . Осталась проблема с неудалением существующих адресных книг